# Remove rows mappedBy a foreign key of another table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables Company and Employees. They have a 1-many relation. I want to delete all rows from Company and set null the column with foreign-key from Employees.

```
@Entity
public class Employees{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int empId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    private Company company;
}

@Entity
public class Company{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int comId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Employees> employees = new LinkedList<>();
}

public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Integer> {
}

public interface EmployeesRepository extends JpaRepository<Employees, Integer> {
}
```

In controller if I just delete Company rows with 
`@Autowired`
`CompanyRepository companyRepo;` 
`companyRepo.deleteAll();` 
it shows of course: 

**`Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`.**


I tried to write an update in `EmployeesRepository` over `Employees` to set company.comId to null, because I want to keep the rows, except `comId` field. In `EmployeesRepository` I wrote:

    `@Modifying`

    `@Query("UPDATE Employees e SET e.company.comId=null")`

    `void removeCompanyId();`

It caused the following error:
**`javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`**

Comment: Did you tried by removing the bidirectional mapping? Just delete the annotations `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn(name="company_id")`

Comment: Remove the Bidirectional mapping, keep mapping only in company table

Comment: It shows the following errror:
"Could not determine type for: Company"